# RXJS how to mapper rest api response to model in application?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Main response model is:

```
export interface TestDataState {
    userDetails: UserDetails | null;
    locationDetails: LocationDetails | null;
    }
```

Each of interfaces:

```
export interface UsersDetails {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    age: number;
    colorEyes: string;
    id: number;
    work: string;
}

export interface LocationDetails {
    city: string;
    building: string;
    departmentId: number;
    floor: number;
    deskId: number;
}
```

Service:

```
public loadUserDataFromApi(): Observable<TestDataState> {
        return this.httpClient.get<ResponseData<TestDataState>>(
            `http://api.com/test`
        ).pipe(
            map(.......)
        );
    }
```

Of course, my response from rest api has a lot of another data, lists etc. - it is not 1:1 to expected model in application, but has all necessary data

```
  {
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 20,
        "colorEyes": "blue",
        "id": 320,
        "work": "barman",
        anotherList: {....},
        anotherList2: {....},
        anotherList3: {....},

        location: {
            "city": "New York",
            "building": "HelloMan",
            "departmentId": 11,
            "floor": 2,
            "deskid": 1
        }
      anotherList5: {....},
      anotherList6: {....}
    }
}
```

**Question:**

It is possible to map it in loadUserDataApi method?

Comment: Sure it is. If u tell me the api response i show u how to map. What does the json look like

Comment: Thank You! I updated my question with json response from api. The best solution for me will be mapping it to one general model -> TestDataState.

Comment: I edited question and put there full json. And I would like to parse it to TestDataState interface, which inlcude two interface: User and Location. Like in the question. There is operator to merge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public loadUserDataFromApi(): Observable<TestDataState> {
        return this.httpClient.get<ResponseData>(
            `http://api.com/test`
        ).pipe(
            map(res => {
              let userDetails = {
                name: res.data.name,
                surname: res.data.surname,
                age: res.age,
                colorEyes: res.data.colorEyes,
                id: res.data.id,
                work: res.data.work
              };

              let locDetails = res.data.location;
               return {
                 userDetails: userDetails as UserDetails,
                 locationDetails: locDetails as LocationDetails
               } as TestDataState
            })
        );
    }
}
```

**But:**

If u have influence on how the backend delivers data, you should use a user model, same as u do with location in your http response and nest it in the data object.
Then your code wouldnt need to be that verbose it would look more like this:

```
public loadUserDataFromApi(): Observable<TestDataState> {
            return this.httpClient.get<ResponseData>(
                `http://api.com/test`
            ).pipe(
                map(res => {
                   return {
                     userDetails: res.data.userDetails as UserDetails,
                     locationDetails: res.data.location as LocationDetails
                   } as TestDataState
                })
            );
        }
    }
```

Also I didnt get why you want to embed TestDataState as TYpe in ResponseData, as the type you are receiving by the backend is ResponseData and the type u want to return an observable of is TestDataState, so I changed that too.

Here is a Stackblitz, you can play with it and maybe make a real api call: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sr5tvc)

cheers